# accesskey on mobile browser

Tags: html, xhtml, mobile, mobile-website, mobile-browser

Is accesskey still be supported among the current browsers on mobile? How can I navigate website with accesskey on mobile browser? I have tried to search online but can't find any answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Safari is one of the current "mobile browsers" (see Wiki-Article for more mobile browsers).
According to [Safaris HTML-Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/SafariHTMLRef.pdf) they support accesskey:

> Specifies the access key for
>   accessibility/screen reading.
>
> Related
>   Tags “a” (page 19) “area” (page 20)
>   “button” (page 24) “input” (page 32)
>   “label” (page 34) “legend” (page 34)
>   “textarea” (page 45)
>
> Availability
>   Available in Safari 1.0 and later.
>   Available in iOS 1.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major things that have changed since accesskey for mobile phones with keypads was thought of:

1. Touch Phones don't have
   permanently visible keyboards to map
   anymore.
2. You could do this with
   javascript events if the browser is
   sufficiently advanced.